# Do you need a gambling licence to create a website where you stake virtual items?

Tags: united-kingdom, gambling

In the game ***Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*** you have virtual items (skins) which have a community market value in most cases, in other cases it has a perceived value outside the market (if the item value exceeds the limit of the market).

Would you need to apply for licences with the gambling commission if you created a website that used skins in place of a monetary amount, while also using the skins' value to influence the games odds much like a high monetary stake?

Comment: Gambling involves stakes of value - they do not have to be monetary stakes.

Comment: So could you create something that does allow the gambling of skins, but not register it as a for profit company and just do it as an individual to bypass dealing with the gambling commission? Or would I have to base it all abroad?

Comment: If there are laws that cover gabling in the UK then it doesn't matter a) what you gamble (money, skins, lollypops); its all gambling and b) it doesn't matter where it is based; if it operates in the UK, you must comply with UK law.

Comment: @DaleM, if gambling involves stakes of value, and they do not have to be monetary stakes, how can, for example, a flash slot game allow you to gamble fake coins? Do they not have a value, regardless if they are not truly monetary?

Comment: @Madness 1. I do not know what a "flash slot game" is 2. A lot of things happen that are not strictly speaking legal 3. Tokens may or may not have value - it depends on the context

Comment: You know, like a game, made in Adobe Flash. And slot game, as in slot machine video game. Or any game from Nintendo is also a good example, where you earn tokens and wager them.